# in applescript, how can I send an http header when using curl?

Tags: curl, applescript

I have a functioning shell script that looks something like this (works in Terminal):

```
curl -X POST --compressed -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -H 'x-api-user: hdfjdfpjefpoj' \
  -H 'x-api-key: fpjefpojwpfjmwefpj' \
  https://example.com/api/v1/user/...
```

However, when I try to use this in an Applescript using `do shell script`, I get the error:

```
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
sh: line 1: -H: command not found
sh: line 2: -H: command not found
sh: line 3: https://example.com/api/v1/user/...: No such file or directory
```

Here's the Applescript:

```
do shell script "curl -X POST --compressed -H 'Content-Type:application/json'
  -H 'x-api-user: hdfjdfpjefpoj'
  -H 'x-api-key: fpjefpojwpfjmwefpj'
  https://example.com/api/v1/user/..."
```

I've found some clues suggesting that `do shell script` doesn't behave exactly like Terminal, for security reasons. But I haven't found clues on how to work around this.

The same Applescript without the header info succeeds in passing the URL, but I need to send my credentials in the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because you have the command on multiple lines. Rather than one

The clue is `sh: line 1: -H: command not found`

This indicates that the shell is trying to find a command named **-H** but not finding it.

In most cases commands are always the first word in a command line string.

So this means the -H options are being interpreted as a command because they are the first word on a line.
**-H** is clearly an option to curl and should follow it in the same line.

try it on a single line.

```
do shell script "curl  -X POST --compressed -H 'Content-Type:application/json'  -H 'x-api-user: hdfjdfpjefpoj'  -H 'x-api-key: fpjefpojwpfjmwefpj'  https://example.com/api/v1/user/..."
```

Comment: High five! Appreciate the help.